# How to flatten a Promise within a Promise?

Tags: javascript, promise

I have the following 2 functions, each returns a Promise:

```
const getToken = () => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    fs.readFile('token.txt', (err, data) => {
      if (err) { return reject(err) }
      if (!tokenIsExpired(data.token)) {
        return resolve(data.token)
      } else {
        return requestNewToken()
      }
    })
  })
}

const requestNewToken = () => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    restClient.get(url, (data, res) => {
      fs.writeFile('tokenfile.txt', data.token, err => {
        resolve(data.token)
      })
    })
  })
}

function1()
  .then(value => {
    console.log('taco')
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.log(err)
  })
```

So `function1` runs, and (depending on some condition), it sometimes returns `function2`, which is returning another Promise. In this code, when `function2` is called, the `console.log('taco')` never runs. Why is this? I thought that if you return a Promise from within a Promise, the resolved value of the nested Promise is what is resolved at the top level.

In order for me to get this to work, I have to do this:

```
const getToken = () => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    if (!tokenIsExpired()) {
      return resolve(getToken())
    } else {
      return requestNewToken ()
        .then(value => {
          resolve(value)
        })
    }
  })
}
```

That works, but it seems like I'm doing something wrong. It seems like there should be a more elegant way to handle/structure this.

Comment: is it nesessary for function 2 to return a promise?

Comment: Or can you write `const function1 = () => { if (someCondition) { return Promise.resolve('foobar') } else { return function2() } }`?

Comment: Why are you using promises at all? Your code is synchronous. If not, please [edit] your question to show us your actual code.

Comment: "*That works*" - actually it doesn't for rejections. "*it seems like I'm doing something wrong*" - Yes indeed, that's the [`Promise` constructor antipattern](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572?What-is-the-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-to-avoid-it)!

Comment: I agree with @Bergi. As the code is posted here you should just go with a synchronous solution otherwise please elaborate on what you are trying to do.

Comment: I'm not showing all my code because I'm trying to simplify it for people to read. But yes, they need to return Promises (or callbacks). In reality, function1 uses `fs.exists` and `fs.readFile` and function2 connects to a REST API and pulls some values and then uses `fs.writeFile`. Lots of asynchronous things happening in both functions. It is not synchronous. I have added some comments to my code to indicate that yes, asynchronous things happen.

Comment: Thanks @Bergi perhaps you could help me rewrite this properly? I don't understand the antipattern issue here.

Comment: @JakeWilson Maybe you should ask a separate question for that, with the whole unsimplified code, otherwise I can't really rewrite it.

Comment: The unsimplified code is literally 100 lines of code. You think that would actually help? Seems like that would just confuse people. Seems a lot more simple to just say "// async code here"...

Comment: I have added more explicit code to show the actual async functions being called. Any help would be appreciated beyond just saying "you're doing it's wrong". Thanks,

Comment: @Bergi I've been reading about the Antipattern. Its saying I should return the Promise as opposed to using .then() within the first function. I am returning the Promise in the first example but it's not working. Can you explain the problem?

Comment: It says you should *chain* a `.then()` *onto* the `new Promise` (if that is necessary at all), and `return` from the `then`callback function. You should  *never* use other promises, or even `then`, within the `new Promise` callback function.

Comment: Ah that is finally making sense. Thank you for your patience sir! Feel free to leave a proper answer below for credit.

Answer (score 1):

You're right that promises auto-unwrap, but in this case you're returning from inside a promise constructor, which is ignored, you need to invoke either `resolve` or `reject` instead of using `return`. I think this might be the solution you're looking for:

```
const function1 = () => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    if (someCondition) {
      resolve('foobar')
    } else {
      resolve(function2());
    }
  })
}
```

Inside a promise constructor, you need to call `resolve` or `reject`, which are equivalent to using `return` or `throw` from inside a `then` callback.

If you find this distinction confusing (I do), you should avoid the promise constructor entirely by just beginning a new chain with `Promise.resolve`, like this:

```js
const function1 = () => {
  return Promise.resolve().then(() => {
    if (someCondition) {
      return 'foobar';
    } else {
      return function2();
    }
  })
}

const function2 = () => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    resolve('hello world')
  })
}
someCondition = false;
function1()
  .then(value => {
    console.log(value)
  })
```

With your updated code, I recommend using a library to wrap APIs, rather than accessing the promise constructor yourself. For example, using bluebird's [promisify](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.promisify.html):

```
const bluebird = require('bluebird');
const readFile = bluebird.promisify(fs.readFile);
const writeFile = bluebird.promisify(fs.writeFile);
const getUrl = bluebird.promisify(restClient.get, {multiArgs:true});

const getToken = () => {
  return readFile('token.txt')
    .then((data) => {
      if(!tokenIsExpired(data.token)) {
        return data.token;
      } else {
        return requestNewToken();
      }
    });
};

const requestNewToken = () => {
    return getUrl(url)
      .then(([data, res]) => {
        return writeFile('tokenFile.txt', data.token)
          .then(() => data.token);
      });
};
```

I've remained faithful to your source code, but I'll note there may be a bug to do with writing `data.token`, and later trying to read the `token` property in that file.

Why use a library instead of the Promise constructor?

- It allows you to write code which deals only with promises, which is (hopefully) easier to understand
- You can be confident that callback APIs are correctly converted without losing errors. For example, if your `tokenIsExpired` function throws an error, using your promise constructor code, it would be lost. You would need to wrap all of your inner callback code in `try {} catch(e) {reject(e)}`, which is a hassle and easily forgotten.

Comment: s/can/should :-)

Comment: these examples does not trigger the promise from function2

Comment: @Poku What do you mean by "trigger"?

Comment: @Bergi that this code will not print out Helle world to the console.

Comment: @Poku `function1().then(console.log)` works just fine for me

Comment: Is it acceptable to resolve a Promise? `resolve(new Promise(){...})`?? I have never seen that before.

Comment: Yep, it's totally fine. Here's the relevant section in the original spec https://promisesaplus.com/#point-49

Essentially the promise under construction adopts the state of the inner promise.

Comment: @JakeWilson Yes, it's acceptable - that's basically what also happens when you `return` a promise from a `then` callback. But in general `resolve(promise)` should never be done, as creating promises inside the `Promise` constructor is [said antipattern](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572?What-is-the-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-to-avoid-it).